# Animated/interactive mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to achieve adding an interactive mouse pointer, similar to the one on [this page](http://2f-design.fr/themes/starry/). I have inspected the source code for quite some time and haven't been able to figure it out at all.

What code is required to animate the mouse pointer in the same way as this page?

Comment: This is not related to mouse pointers but to some `<canvas>` element that calculates using JS  the mouse position - and draws lines and dots.

Comment: Please make sure to read: [ask] and make always sure to create a [mcve]

Comment: I had no idea where to start in building the code, hence the question. The simple suggestion of 'canvas' is a big help in itself

Comment: You're welcome! (That's why I used the comments section instead of providing a link-only answer to a link-only question (both of which are not in the expected Q&A format for StackOverflow))

Comment: Understood and aware. I'll be closing the question shortly, I just needed some guidance and pointing in the right direction

Comment: Sadly you cannot directly delete the question (since there is an active undeleted answer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Minified code is here - http://2f-design.fr/themes/starry/wp-content/themes/starry/js/header-pointer.js?ver=1.0

Basically it is just a canvas with event listener on `mousemove` event that erases/redrow same constellations over and over

```
// Event handling
function addListeners() {
    if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var posx = posy = 0;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    target.x = posx;
    target.y = posy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vittore, exactly what I was after